# Firebase Cloud Messages not being delivered when using multiple topics in condition

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm facing a problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging for some time.
My Android application can be subscribed to one of two topic (either `AtopicA` or `BtopicB`). My backend system uses request to Firebase's API in order to send a messages to users of application.

The request (made to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/messages:send` looks as follow:

```
{
"message": {
    "condition": "'AtopicA' in topics || 'BtopicB' in topics",
    "data": {
        "news": "Something new",
        "title": "OUR_TITLE_OF_MESSAGE",
        "ourOwnID": "firebase-debug-test-v10"
    }
}
```

}

It was working ok, but something has changed quite recently.
After long investigations I've figured out, that when using just one topic in the condition - e.g. using just `"condition": "'AtopicA' in topics"` - it works ok and messages are being delivered.
However, when using combined condition, it fails.

I've already tried several things:

- Using another project on Firebase - the same situation
- Testing other application - the same
- Using previous legacy API instead of the present one - the same
- Checking FFCM Diagnostics (by dialing `*#*#426#*#*` on phone) - messages sent with combined topics are not listed. Messages sent with single topic in condition are listed.

Is there anything wrong at the Firebase's side? Has anything changed in its configuration recently (as I said - our solution with two topics combined in condition was working well for a long time)?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research into it, and your template looks like it should be valid. The only thing that I found was a case insensitivity with the topic conditions, of which the Solution was to report it to Firebase Support as a Bug and further diagnosis.

Since this was working previously until now, this is the most sound solution as a bug may have been introduced with the topics handler.

https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted Firebase Support, which confirmed similar reports being sent to the support team recently.
So it indeed looks like a problem at Firebase's end. Unfortunately, there wasn't able to share any timeline for fixing that isssue. I also cannot see any outage reported at Firebase status webpage.

Is there anyone from Firebase Dev Team here, who could actualy say what's going on? :)